# Cannot access docker port 8000 via wsl2

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed wsl2 , i have ubuntu in it, i have docker in windows enabled wsl2 integration for docker desktop software....my team sent me a docker to run it runs on port 8000, but i am dumb i dont know how to access it, they told they use vbox and port forward 127.0.0.1 to access it from localhost

I want to access it moreover i want to check it whether it works or not i tried curl localhost:8000

In ubuntu of wsl
In Windows browser

[image]

I am new so do tell what information you all want i can provide

[image]

Comment: As a new user, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Since your question doesn't involve any programming, it's also off-topic here. Please check when you ask for what are valid topics.

Comment: Is this question and answer similar/helpful ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002681/connecting-to-wsl2-server-via-local-network/62438375#62438375