# running a Development server on NextJS (on the network)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

While using ReactJS, when we use the command npm start, It starts the development server on localhost:3000 and also on the network, 192.168.1.2:3000
This was super easy, I could test my app on all the devices by going into that address.

Recently I started learning NextJS and when I run the command npm run dev, I only see that it starts the development server on the local machine, not on the network. Is there a way to make it work just like it did with pure reactjs?

[image: posting the screenshot, this is what it looks like with nextjs]

Comment: For me the issue was I was running nextjs in WSL2.  I needed to follow this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002681/connecting-to-wsl2-server-via-local-network

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It also listens on your local IP, just find out your local ip and do "192.168.1.x:3000" -- this would be your IP , you will see the server running on that port.

To find local IP:
Open your terminal and run the command `ipconfig` for windows or `ifconfig` for MacBook. You'll see the network you're currently connected to, the IPv4 address being the current local IP address.

Comment: Tried that and it wasn't working on local IP. Had to run it manually
`npm run dev -- -H 192.168.x.x`. Also `ifconfig` not working, had to use `ip addr show`

Comment: For Windows, make sure that your device is visible via "network profile" > "private". If set to "public", your device will not be found.

Comment: On Windows, I had to disable Firewall on `Private Network` and set the WiFi's `Network Profile` to `Private`

Comment: On Windows, I opened ports in Defender but still no joy. Does this method assume that the IP address identified using ipconfig is a WiFi adapter? My dev machine running the website on localhost is Ethernet wired to the router and I'm trying to access it from my mobile devices connected to the same router over WiFi.

Comment: @AvinashThakur comment's pointed me to the right direction, and [this article](https://4sysops.com/archives/change-windows-network-profiles-between-public-and-private/) helped me resolve the issue. I changed the connection of my pc to the wi-fi to private and my phone could find it :)

Answer (score 19):

As @Deepinder Singh mentioned, Next.js dev server already listens on your local network.

To get your local network IP address run the following command. (tested only on mac)

```
ipconfig getifaddr en0
```

### Edit

for *macOS* users, use the following command, it'll print your private ip address like "Private IP address: 192.168.1.45"

```
echo "Private IP address:" $(ifconfig $(route -n get default | awk '/interface: / {print $2}') | awk '/inet / {print $2}')
```

for *Linux* users, use the following command,

```
echo "Private IP address:" $(ip addr show $(ip route | awk '/default/ {print $5}') | awk '/inet / {print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1)
```

for *Windows* users, I recommand you to change to a unix-like OS :)

Answer (score 9):

**Mac/Linux**

To find your local IP easily, you can use:

```
ifconfig | grep 'inet '
```

[image]

Then if you're on the same network, just navigate to `http://YOUR_LOCAL_IP:3000`

Answer (score 3):

I can see you may be confused by the addres "0.0.0.0" you're seeing. But kindly go to your terminal and check your local ip address using the following command

ipconfig

then check the IPV4 address you see and use it instead of "0.0.0.0" and you're good to go.. for instance "192.168.43.131:3000"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

For connecting other devices for debugging, make sure both devices are connected to same network (WiFi).

- Search for the ip address of the network you are connected, In my case I'm using Mac, you can enter this command in the terminal :
  `ipconfig getifaddr en0`
- In your Nextjs project run the project in this way:
  `npm run dev -- -H /your_ip_address/` 
  for example - `npx next dev -H 192.168.1.2`

Explore more on - [NextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#development)

**Happy coding :)**

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answers, MacOS and popular Linux distros will use your local hostname and broadcast over [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS).

For example, if your hostname is `meow` and your Next.js dev server is on `localhost:3000` then you can reach the server with another device over the local network at `meow.local:3000`.