# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND when starting Next.js DEV server with IP and port

Tags: windows, next.js, browser, microsoft-edge, lan

Whenever I try to run a dev server (be it Vite, or a NextJS application, or live-server) in LAN (192.168.1.7:3000 like so), I always get this error.

[Screenshot of error as shown in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByrEy.png)

I am working on **Windows** and I have run dev servers in LAN before in my PC. But something has changed but I have no clue about it.
Has anyone else faced this issue?

I tried the answers given in [running a Development server on NextJS (on the network)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68254828/running-a-development-server-on-nextjs-on-the-network) for a next js application that I'm building at the moment, but still no luck.
Result from trying to run the server manually:

```
npx next dev  -- -H 192.168.1.7:3000 
- error Failed to start server
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 192.168.1.7:3000
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: '192.168.1.7:3000'
```

Running manually on specific port as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77031263/16612987).

```
 npx next dev  -- -H 192.168.1.7 -p 3000
- ready started server on 192.168.1.7:3000, url: http://192.168.1.7:3000
- event compiled client and server successfully in 219 ms (20 modules)
- wait compiling...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 168 ms (20 modules)
```

Error in the browser still prevailed.

#### Update

I found out that this issue arises only in **Edge**. The site is working completely fine in Chrome. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Try disabling extensions in Edge, resetting settings, or using InPrivate mode. Do these methods work?

Comment: Yeah, I reset the settings, and it works fine now.

Comment: OK, glad your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the `-H` option, you must specify the host only, not the host and the port.

Use `-H 192.168.1.7 -p 3000` instead, to specify the bind host and port.

See also:  https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-cli

Comment: I tried this too. Still did not work and the error still prevailed