# Consuming Kafka: the basics

Tags: apache-kafka

I am very new to Kafka. Following a few tutorials, I have the following questions regarding consuming actual Kafka topics.

The situation: there is a server in my workplace that is streaming Kafka topics. I have the topic name. I would like to consume this topic from my machine (Windows WSL2 Ubuntu). From [this tutorial](https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/#install-java), I am able to

- Run `zookeeper` with this command:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

- Create a broker with:

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

- Run a producer console, with a fake `topic` named `quickstart-events` at port `localhost:9092`:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

- Run a consumer console listening to `localhost:9092` and receive the streaming data from the producer:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic quickstart-events --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

Now for my real situation: if I know the topic name, what else do I need in order to apply the same steps above to listen to it as a consumer? What are the steps involved? I read in other threads about `tunnelling` with `Jumphost`. How to do that?

I understand this question is rather generic. Appreciate any pointers to any relevant readings or guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your company nameserver the next procedure should be done in your wsl instance
To gain outside connection

[unable to access network from WSL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633406/unable-to-access-network-from-wsl)

You need to set bootstrap-server to your company server

--bootstrap-server my.company.com:9092

Comment: So I can use the same command for ```console-consumer```. But I need to replace the localhost:9092 with my company IP address and port, xx.xx.xx.xx : xxxx. Thanks for advising. I will try this.

Comment: Basically yes, you need access from your wsl to the company server , I suggest to use fqdn and not ip 

Comment: I got the full domain name from IT and it works !